# Increase size of image of click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Its pretty simple to see what I mean if you look at the image, which I also need to shrink back if you click it again, it needs to be animated as well:

[The image link http://www.keironlowecreative.x10hosting.com/Help.png](http://www.keironlowecreative.x10hosting.com/Help.png)

Comment: I dunno what happened, the link is there now anyway

Comment: Do you want it to be animated? if so, there's the $.animate command that you can customize for that.

Comment: Yes I want it to be animated but I dont know much about jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
   $("#what > img").click(function () {
      $("img").toggle("slow");
   });    
});
```

html

```
<div id="what">
  <img src="small_img" />
  <img src="big_img" style="display: none" />
</div>
```

[toggle](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/toggle)

Comment: This works kinda right except I need it to be animated and when I click it the logo image dissapears

Comment: by the way I dont mean I wont the logo to dissapear, I mean it does dissapear

Comment: the toggle("slow") should animate, look at the examples provided in the link. the first dissapears, the second appears, isn't it what the question was? small image toggles with big image.

Comment: This is what happens, its different from what I explained before but still not working properly
http://www.keironlowecreative.x10hosting.com/

Comment: Oh and by the way, ive changed them from images to div's, with the images as the background image

Comment: The problem now is that I cant close it again and the way the 2 boxes kind of merge at the end of the animation

Comment: because you assigned the click action to one button instead to all img (or div if u want) objects in the container. replace img in my code with div and #what with #wrapper

Comment: I changed the images to square rectangles instead of rounded ones and it fixed the merging issue but is there a way to make it grow only right instead of down and right?

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of the [horizontal accordion](http://www.portalzine.de/Horizontal_Accordion_Plugin_2/index.html) plugins for this.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse the inline styles... Pixels aren't exact.  Use the same image twice, one div on top of the other:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="position:relative; height:20px;">
  <div id="top" style="background:url(...) top left no-repeat; position:absolute; height: 20px; width:18px; top:0; left:0; z-index:2;"></div>
  <div id="under" style="background:url(...) top right no-repeat; position:absolute; height:20px; width:20px; top:0; left:2px; z-index:1;"></div>
</div>
```

So the top div is showing the plus and the left corner.  The bottom div is showing the right corner - over two pixels so it's not showing under the corners of the top element.  If the image is opaque, this doesn't matter...

Animate the width of the under div to get the effect.  No fading, only one image.  Should be small and quick to animate.

Comment: I cant get this to work, i entered the styles into the css and it doesnt work.